# Gauge fields in 2d spacetime

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory

I believe it is only a technical question. However I cannot realize it. It is said in 2d spacetime the gauge fields $A_\mu$ can be rewritten in lightcone coordinates as $A_+=ig\partial_+g^{-1}$ and $A_-=ih\partial_-h^{-1}$, where $g$ and $h$ are the elements of the gauge group.

Anyone could give me a simple and transparent explanation on it? Thanks!

Comment: Which text are you reading?

Comment: @Qmechanic I am reading Polyakov and Wiegman's paper, in which they used this gauge to calculate fermionic functional determinant.

Comment: Found it: A.M. Polyakov and P.B Wiegmann, [Phys. Lett. B131 (1983) 121](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0370-2693(83)91104-8).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A rough sketch:

Suppose you start with $A_1$ and $A_2$ being in some configuration. Then by means of a gauge transformation, you can gauge away one component, $A_1 \to A_1' = A_1 + h\, \partial_1 h^{-1}$

where $h^{-1} = \mathcal{P} e^{\int_{-\infty}^{x_1} dx_1 A_1}$ is the holonomy of $A_1$ along a line of constant $x_2$

The point is you can choose $h$ so that $A_1' = 0$. Notice now that $A_2'$ also picks up this gauge transformation, because $A_2 \to A_2' = A_2 + h\, \partial_2 h^{-1}$.

No matter. We perform another gauge transformation, this time working with $A_2'$, to get $A_2' \to A_2'' = A_2' + g \,\partial_2 g^{-1}$ which we can use to set cancel out the first term in $A_2' = A_2 + h\, \partial_2 h^{-1}$ (i.e., the $A_2$). But now this $g$ also affects $A_1'$:

$A_1'' =  g\, \partial_1 g^{-1}$

All said and done, we end up with

$A_1'' =  g\, \partial_1 g^{-1}$

$A_2'' =  h\, \partial_2 h^{-1}$

as desired.